# Condtional statements using Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY

Tags: java, android

I have this code and it has to show one of the strings based on the time of the day.
The code is

```
public void onTimeTick() {
    mTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Let's see what string we need according to the time
    int saluteResId = R.string.salute_fallback;

    if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 4) {
        saluteResId = R.string.salute_morning;
    } else if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 12) {
        saluteResId = R.string.salute_evening;
    } else if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 19 ||  mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 5) {
        saluteResId = R.string.salute_night;
    }

}
```

But the problem is that HOUR_OF_DAY will always remain greater than 4 so it will never even check the remaining two conditions and the string will always be set to salute_morning. I am not very good in java and trying to figure out how I can make the first condition false so it will check the other conditions and set the string according to them.

Comment: If you run your if checks in the opposite order, the `> 4` one won't clobber the `> 12` one. etc.

Comment: reverse them, start from  `>19` then `>12` and finally  `>4`

Comment: Wait this is it.. Damn I really couldn't think of reversing the order. Thanks a lot guys I am 99% sure now that it will work.

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be helpful

```
 if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 4 && mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= 12) {
     //saluteResId = R.string.salute_morning;
 } else if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 12 && mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= 19) {
     //saluteResId = R.string.salute_evening;
 } else if (mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 19 &&  mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= 4) {
     //saluteResId = R.string.salute_night;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
final Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        
        
        final int hh = d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        
        
        //try this way


        String time = null;

        if (hh == 0) {
   
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 1) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 2) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 3) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 4) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 5) {
           
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 6) {
            
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 7) {
           
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 8) {
           
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 9) {
            
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 10) {
           
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 11) {
           
            time =("Salute_Morning");
        } else if (hh == 12) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 13) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 14) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 15) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 16) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 17) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 18) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 19) {
            
            time =("Salute_Evening");
        } else if (hh == 20) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 21) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 22) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        } else if (hh == 23) {
            
            time =("Salute_Night");
        }
       
//your text view where you want it to display

textviewTimeOfDay.settext.(time);
```

Comment: I am not that good at java but i can really say that this is not the best way to do that.

Comment: @Priyanshu Yes you can shorten the code. But it is easy and works fine for me.